# VBnet Call sub from module

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a module named "clsCustomer.vb" how can I use the sub "CustomerInputOk" from that module in my main form "frmMain"? I am trying to call via:

If Not CustomerInputOK() Then Exit Sub

I have tried prefixing the call "clsCustomer.CustomerInputOK()" but that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the CustomerInputOK method [shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared):

```
Public Shared Function CustomerInputOK() As Boolean
```

Notice that it is Public.  CustomerInputOK will need to have an [access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels) that permits your frmMain to access it, such as Friend or Public.

Or, again following the access modifier rule, you can instantiate an instance of clsCustomer and then call the method.

```
Dim objMyInstanceOfCustomerClass As New clsCustomer()

If Not objMyInstanceOfCustomerClass.CustomerInputOK() Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: I had public set when I was getting this error. I tried placing the Dim and If statements in my main form but the dim statement shows it doesn't know what clsCustomer() is.

Comment: Can you please show how clsCustomer is defined?  That will have to be Public or Friend too (friend is for when they exist in the same assembly).

Comment: I have a module called clsCustomer.vb and within that is my "Public Class Customer" on top. Once you asked about how it is defined I thought maybe its the name of the class and not the vb file thats wrong, but changing the class to clsCustomer and calling clsCustomer.CustomerInputOK() didn't work either. That just gives another error in frmMain: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" Here's the main form: https://pastebin.com/XvGRQ8J1 and the module: https://pastebin.com/qXgcvtEN

Comment: @N0Alias `Public Shared CustomerInputOK() As Boolean` looks like a public field, an array of boolean. Wouldn't that be `Public Share Function CustomerInputOK() As Boolean`? Or am I confused?

Comment: Adding the "public shared" portion to my subs, then explicitly calling them using the form name prefixed before the actual sub name worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If CustomerInputOK is a sub it cannot be used in an If statement that way. You would want...

```
Public Class Customer
    Public Function CustomerInputOK(SomeInput As String) As Boolean
        'Your code here
        Return True 'or False
    End Function
End Class
```

Then in your form...

```
Private Sub VerifyInput()
        Dim CustomerInput As String = "Some Input"
        Dim cust As New Customer
        If cust.CustomerInputOK(CustomerInput) Then

        End If
End Sub
```